# Editing list of strings using Google Earth Engine?

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, string

I'm trying to edit string elements in a list object. I need to get a list of IDs of a image collection, and then replace the orbit row to another (in this case, 073 to 074). I'm new to GEE and got stucked creating the .map() function. Does anyone know how can I solve this?

```
var landsat = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LT05/C01/T1_SR')
    .filterDate('2008-01-01', '2011-12-31')
    .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(6,7,'month'))
    .filter(ee.Filter.eq('WRS_PATH', 222))
    .filter(ee.Filter.eq('WRS_ROW', 73))
    .filterMetadata('CLOUD_COVER', 'equals', 0)

var names = ee.List(landsat.aggregate_array('system:index'));
print(names)

var replace = function(i){
  var size = (i.size().subtract(1)) // get list size
  var imgs = ee.List.sequence(0, 11) // creates list sequence to iterate
  var replace = imgs.map(function(j) {
    var str = ee.String(i.get(j)) // convert each element to a string
    var str2 = str.replace('222073','222074')
    var newlist = []
    return newlist.add(str2)
  })
} 
var newnames = names.map(replace)
```

What I have:

1. LT05_222073_20080604
2. LT05_222073_20080706
3. LT05_222073_20080722
4. LT05_222073_20100626
5. LT05_222073_20110715

What I need:

1. LT05_222074_20080604
2. LT05_222074_20080706
3. LT05_222074_20080722
4. LT05_222074_20100626
5. LT05_222074_20110715

Answer (score 2):

When you `map` over `names`, which is a list of the ids, the argument of the function would be each element of that list, thus the name. So you'd only need to rename that name

```js
var landsat = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LT05/C01/T1_SR')
    .filterDate('2008-01-01', '2011-12-31')
    .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(6,7,'month'))
    .filter(ee.Filter.eq('WRS_PATH', 222))
    .filter(ee.Filter.eq('WRS_ROW', 73))
    .filterMetadata('CLOUD_COVER', 'equals', 0)

var names = ee.List(landsat.aggregate_array('system:index'));
print(names)

var replace = function(name){
  return ee.String(name).replace('073', '074')
} 
var newnames = names.map(replace)
print(newnames)
```

[link](https://code.earthengine.google.com/37dccd772da3856d8e4ff3e8621c9ff6)